# Mime type on FileSystem Api of Google Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, filesystems

I'm developing an extension for Google Chrome that generates an mp3 file and saves it to localstorage using the FileSystem API. When I save I specify the mime type "application/octec-stream". Later I send the user the file url, instead of downloading the file, the browser starts playing it on the html5 player. Looking the response it's clear that the mime type returned was "audio/mp3" based on the extension of the file. 
The question is: How can I efficiently make the browser download the file instead of playing it? Here's the small snippet of what i'm doing on javascript.

```
 fs.root.getFile(contextData.songInfo.Name + ".mp3", { create: true }, function (fileEntry) {

         // Create a FileWriter object for our FileEntry (log.txt).
         fileEntry.createWriter(function (fileWriter) {

             fileWriter.onwriteend = function (e) {
                 console.log('Write completed.');
             };

             fileWriter.onerror = function (e) {
                 console.log('Write failed: ' + e.toString());
             };

             var bb = new window.WebKitBlobBuilder();
             bb.append(buffer);
             fileWriter.write(bb.getBlob('application/octet-stream'));

             contextData.fileUrl = fileEntry.toURL();

             callback(contextData);

         }, errorHandler);



     }, errorHandler);
```

Comment: MIME types only exist in the HTTP protocol, for the file system they are always deduced from the file extension. It seems that Chrome treats files created with the FileSystem API the same which makes sense.

Comment: The problem is that when I redirect the user to the file's URL, i'm again in HTTP world, and would be reasonable to let me decide which mime type to send along with the http response. I don't want the user to hear the file in the browser, they need to save it. Right now I add a .download extension and ir triggers the download, but the file has to be renamed later by the user, which is a pain. Maybe encapsulate the file in a .zip, but again the user has take action and decompress before using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `a[download]` attribute, and set the `href` to the `filesystem:` URL

```
<a href="filesystem:..." download="FileName">Download it!</a>
```

This will force the browser to download the resource rather than navigating to it :) THere's more explanation here: http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/08/Downloading-resources-in-HTML5-a-download